in laravel ajax keyup search not properly working
in routes:
`Route::post('search/product/name',[App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\IndexController::class, 'searchProduct'])->name('search.product');
Route::post('search/product/code',[App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\IndexController::class, 'searchProductCode'])->name('search.product.code');`

in controller:
`public function searchProduct(Request $request)
    {
        $search_text = $request->search_text;
        $search = Product::where('name','LIKE',"%".$search_text."%")->get();

        return response()->json($search);
    }

    public function searchProductCode(Request $request)
    {
        $search_text = $request->search_text;
        $search = Product::where('sku','LIKE',"%".$search_text."%")->get();

        return response()->json($search);
    }`

in script- ajax code:
`$(document).on('keyup','input.search', function (){

                let search_text = $(this).val();
                const main_url = 'http://localhost:8000';

                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{ route('search.product') }}",
                    method: "POST",
                    type: "json",
                    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                    data: {search_text:search_text},
                    success: function (data){
                        console.log(data)
                                var bodyName = '';
                                $.each(data,function (key,value){
                                    bodyName += `

                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="card shadow-sm my-3">
                                        <div class="card-body product-cart">
                                            <img id="img" style="width: 150px; height: 200px;" src="${main_url}/uploads/products/${value.image}" alt="">
                                            <p id="name">${value.name}</p>
                                            <div class="price">
                                            <p><strong>Selling Price:</strong><del>${value.selling_price}</del></p>
                                            <p><strong>Purchase Price:</strong>${value.purchase_price}</p>
                                </div>
                                <p id="sku"><strong>SKU:</strong>${value.sku}</p>
                                            <a type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" id="addToCart" product_id="${value.id}" class="btn btn-info add-cart" href="#">Add to Cart</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                `
                                    $('.searchBody').html(bodyName)
                                });


                        }

                })


            });





        $(document).on('keyup','input.search', function (e){


            let search_text = $(this).val();
            const main_url = 'http://localhost:8000';

            $.ajax({
                url: main_url + "/search/product/code",
                method: "POST",
                type: "json",
                data: {search_text:search_text},
                success: function (data){
                    var bodyCode = '';
                    $.each(data,function (key,value){
                        bodyCode += `

                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="card shadow-sm my-3">
                                        <div class="card-body product-cart">
                                            <img id="img" style="width: 150px; height: 200px;" src="${main_url}/uploads/products/${value.image}" alt="">
                                            <p id="name">${value.name}</p>
                                            <div class="price">
                                            <p><strong>Selling Price:</strong><del>${value.selling_price}</del></p>
                                            <p><strong>Purchase Price:</strong>${value.purchase_price}</p>
                                </div>
                                <p id="sku"><strong>SKU:</strong>${value.sku}</p>
                                            <a type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" id="addToCart" product_id="${value.id}" class="btn btn-info add-cart" href="#">Add to Cart</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                `

                    });
                    $('.searchBody').html(bodyCode)

                }

            })


        });`

if i want to search by keyup event both sku value and product name, problem is if i search by product name data can not show although in console its show all search data although SKU search is properly working.If i search by name means product name its just appear just a moment and vanish.plz help
